# Neoload SQL ODBC database configuration

Tags: sql, database, configuration, odbc, neoload

i have the task to connect NeoLoad to an ODBC oracle database for getting actual test data variables. My approach is to import a new variable type SQL and select Oracle as the driver and put in all the details i have.

When filling in the database configuration, i get the error

`ORA-12505 TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

...which means, i miss the correct connection details. In this case, i only have a service name given and no SID.

`connection_string_lt = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=a.b.c.com)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=d.world)));uid=user;pwd=pwd"`

When trying to get around this by selecting a custom database configuration, NeoLoad wants me to put a driver class and an URL.
However, i had difficulties to find the correct connection URL as it does not match with the connection data i have as well as the driver class, which i don't know where to get from (should i ask the database administrator ?).

Could somebody support me with how the input should look like for this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When searching for a way to convert the URL i found this example suitable for connecting via server name. Is this the right thing to use ?

username/password@host:port/SERVICE_NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neoload has its own "SQL Connection" action which helps to connect with database and execute queries. To connect with Oracle it requires connection URL which can be in below format.
**jdbc:oracle:thin:@//Hostname:1521/servicename**

Username and Password of the Schema you need to access needs to be provided in required space.

[Screenshot for connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6EkB.png)